# HTML5 responsive width video makes parent container height expanded in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, html5-video

I'm trying to get a layout of HTML5 video's in a 2 by X layout (where X is any number of rows). This is unfortunately being problematic in IE11 whereby the height of the parent container is staying at the height it would be if I didn't specify a width on the video, and I can't find a way around it.

Example code to reproduce the issue:

```css
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sfSite-section {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  padding: 30px 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.sfVideoList {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sfVideoList-videoContainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
.sfVideoList-videoClose {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #2a2c35;
  top: 0;
}
.sfVideoList-video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="sfSite-section" role="main">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque et tellus sit amet iaculis. Donec sodales laoreet ipsum, vitae ultrices sapien viverra id. Mauris suscipit convallis metus tempor suscipit. Morbi ac dignissim erat. Nulla fringilla
    quam nisl, convallis auctor justo aliquam eget. Aliquam vitae urna tellus. Duis consectetur, nisl ut gravida efficitur, nisl ex auctor orci, nec luctus felis urna at tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
    himenaeos. Aenean id porta eros. Phasellus ut metus at lectus efficitur egestas eu sit amet ex. Sed accumsan id leo eget mollis. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  <p>Cras efficitur eros urna, sit amet finibus diam mollis et. Suspendisse eros tellus, mollis eu facilisis quis, placerat non magna. Vestibulum eget dictum leo. Phasellus mauris velit, suscipit in ipsum sed, porta s agittis massa. Curabitur diam nisi,
    consectetur eu mollis in, sodales sit amet quam. Cras cursus eu metus nec luctus. Ut posuere quis arcu vel eleifend.</p>

  <div class="sfVideoList">
    <div class="sfVideoList-videoContainer">
      <i class="fa fa-times sfVideoList-videoClose" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <video class="sfVideoList-video" controls>
        <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>

    <div class="sfVideoList-videoContainer">
      <i class="fa fa-times sfVideoList-videoClose" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <video class="sfVideoList-video" controls>
        <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I've tried using `display:flex` on the container, I've tried using `display:inline-block` on the video's, I've tried setting `height:auto`, all to no avail and now I'm out of ideas. This only seems to happen on large video's. All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this isn't limited to video's, but also happens to images too (I tried changing tactic and had the same issue). When doing a little more googling with less specificity to videos, I stumbled upon this codepen: https://codepen.io/leonderijke/pen/nxFhH

Quite simply the answer is to set the `height` of the container to `0` while setting the `padding-bottom` to be the correct % for the image's aspect ratio.

Here's the code for that codepen, just in case:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

.media {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.media-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.media-image {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56%; /* (Width / Height * 100) */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="media">
    <!--
      This div will get sized based on its children. Necessary, because Firefox doesn't handle the padded box (.media-image) very well as a flex-item.
    -->
    <div>
      <div class="media-image">
        <img src="//placehold.it/600x336.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3>The title</h3>
      <p>
        Just some filler text because Lorum Ipsum is too boring. You know, reasons.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because my images could be any width or height, I had to generate the CSS here using JavaScript sadly. I did make sure this only needed to happen on IE11 though as you can see:

```js
var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;

$(function() {
  if (isIE11) {
    $('.sfVideoList-videoPreviewImg').each(function() {
      var width = $(this).outerWidth();
      var percentage = (($(this).outerHeight() / width) * 100) + '%';

      $(this).css('width', '100%').parent().css({
        'height': '0px',
        'padding-bottom': percentage
      });
      $(this).closest('.sfVideoList').css('height', 'auto');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sfSite-section {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  padding: 30px 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.sfVideoList {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sfVideoList-videoContainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
.sfVideoList-videoPreview {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.sfVideoList-videoPreview::before {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f144";
  font: normal normal normal 3rem/1 FontAwesome;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #2a2c35;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.sfVideoList-videoPreviewImg {
  width: 100%;  
}
.sfVideoList-videoScreen {
  display: none;
}
.sfVideoList-videoClose {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #2a2c35;
  top: 0;
}
.sfVideoList-video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  .sfVideoList {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .sfVideoList-videoPreviewImg {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="sfSite-section" role="main">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque et tellus sit amet iaculis. Donec sodales laoreet ipsum, vitae ultrices sapien viverra id. Mauris suscipit convallis metus tempor suscipit. Morbi ac dignissim erat. Nulla fringilla
    quam nisl, convallis auctor justo aliquam eget. Aliquam vitae urna tellus. Duis consectetur, nisl ut gravida efficitur, nisl ex auctor orci, nec luctus felis urna at tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
    himenaeos. Aenean id porta eros. Phasellus ut metus at lectus efficitur egestas eu sit amet ex. Sed accumsan id leo eget mollis. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  <p>Cras efficitur eros urna, sit amet finibus diam mollis et. Suspendisse eros tellus, mollis eu facilisis quis, placerat non magna. Vestibulum eget dictum leo. Phasellus mauris velit, suscipit in ipsum sed, porta s agittis massa. Curabitur diam nisi,
    consectetur eu mollis in, sodales sit amet quam. Cras cursus eu metus nec luctus. Ut posuere quis arcu vel eleifend.</p>

  <div class="sfVideoList">
    <div class="sfVideoList-videoContainer">

      <div class="sfVideoList-videoPreview">
        <img class="sfVideoList-videoPreviewImg" src="//placehold.it/600x336.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="sfVideoList-videoScreen">
        <i class="fa fa-times sfVideoList-videoClose" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <video class="sfVideoList-video" controls>
          <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sfVideoList-videoContainer">

      <div class="sfVideoList-videoPreview">
        <img class="sfVideoList-videoPreviewImg" src="//placehold.it/600x336.png" />
      </div>


      <div class="sfVideoList-videoScreen">
        <i class="fa fa-times sfVideoList-videoClose" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <video class="sfVideoList-video" controls>
          <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```